# Sub query a "bit slow" how to improve?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery

I've been working for a while with MySQL, and right now I have a problem with some sub query, that takes 60 sec to execute! :( 
I should change this because it seems a "bit slow", and I'm no SQL expert, so I figure I'd ask if there's a smarter way of doing this. This is the current query:

```
SELECT VAR_ID, VAR_REF, DET_VAR_NOMB, DET_VAR_IMG, DET_VAR_MEDIDA, DET_VAR_DETALLE, SEN_FECH, SEN_VALOR
FROM variable, detalle_variable, senal
WHERE equipo_EQO_ID =6
AND detalle_variable_DET_VAR_ID = DET_VAR_ID
AND variable_VAR_ID = VAR_ID
AND SEN_ID
IN (
    SELECT MAX( SEN_ID ) 
    FROM senal
    GROUP BY variable_VAR_ID
)
```

The query result is: (and thats all I wish to select)

VAR_ID  VAR_REF DET_VAR_NOMB    DET_VAR_IMG DET_VAR_MEDIDA  DET_VAR_DETALLE SEN_FECH    SEN_VALOR

8   101 vsth    ../../img/foto/variable/play_blue.png   something   something   2012-05-30 03:14:17 16

The tables look like this:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pgssgc_stap2`.`detalle_variable`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pgssgc_stap2`.`detalle_variable` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pgssgc_stap2`.`detalle_variable` (
  `DET_VAR_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `DET_VAR_NOMB` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `DET_VAR_MEDIDA` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `DET_VAR_DETALLE` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `DET_VAR_IMG` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DET_VAR_ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 101
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;



-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pgssgc_stap2`.`variable`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pgssgc_stap2`.`variable` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pgssgc_stap2`.`variable` (
  `VAR_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `VAR_REF` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `detalle_variable_DET_VAR_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `equipo_EQO_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`VAR_ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_variable_detalle_variable1` (`detalle_variable_DET_VAR_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_variable_equipo1` (`equipo_EQO_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_variable_detalle_variable1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`detalle_variable_DET_VAR_ID` )
    REFERENCES `pgssgc_stap2`.`detalle_variable` (`DET_VAR_ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_variable_equipo1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`equipo_EQO_ID` )
    REFERENCES `pgssgc_stap2`.`equipo` (`EQO_ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 11
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `pgssgc_stap2`.`senal`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pgssgc_stap2`.`senal` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pgssgc_stap2`.`senal` (
  `SEN_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `variable_VAR_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `SEN_FECH` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `SEN_VALOR` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SEN_ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_senal_variable1` (`variable_VAR_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_senal_variable1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`variable_VAR_ID` )
    REFERENCES `pgssgc_stap2`.`variable` (`VAR_ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2086
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I'd look at first at `SELECT MAX( SEN_ID ) 
    FROM senal
    GROUP BY variable_VAR_ID` : is variable_VAR_ID in table senal (big doubt about that) ? Could you give table, relations, and... what you wanna achieve ?

Comment: Yes, please show us `CREATE TABLE` statements for these tables (you can get them using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: For the subquery, you need at least an index on variable_VAR_ID, but ideally a compound index on `(variable_VAR_ID, SEN_ID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have problem with jut the sub query.

Make sure that the column `variable_VAR_ID` of table `senal` is `INDEXED`.